# Error en el ExecuteNonQuery del insert

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un trabajo en c# y cuando hago el insert me tira el error y se me tilda en la línea `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` que me dice

> sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '1'

Aquí les paso el código:

```
string stConexion = @"Data Source=BRIAN-PC; Initial Catalog=persona; Integrated Security=true;";
            SqlConnection oleConn = new SqlConnection(stConexion);
            oleConn.Open();
            string stSql = "Insert Into vendedor(NombreyApellido,Documento,Categoria,sueldo,edad)";
            stSql += "Values('{0}',{1},'{2}',{3},{4})";


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stSql, oleConn);
            cmd.Connection = oleConn;
            for (int i = count; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                stSql = string.Format(stSql, 
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value, 
                   Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value), 
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), 
                   Convert.ToInt32( dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value),
                   Convert.ToInt32( dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value));

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            oleConn.Close();
```

Aquí les dejo una foto más ilustrativa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías de editar la pregunta y añadir la imagen que pusiste en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Dos Cosas:

1. Uno de tus errores es que primero le envias a tu SqlCommand la variable stSql y luego la formateas. Lo correcto seria formatear la cadena y luego enviarla al SqlCommand.
2. Si haces un bucle para grabar, lo correcto seria que crees tu instancia del SqlCommand dentro del bucle.

Intenta hacerlo asi:

```
for (int i = count; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    string stSql = "Insert Into vendedor(NombreyApellido,Documento,Categoria,sueldo,edad)";
    stSql += "Values('{0}',{1},'{2}',{3},{4})";
    stSql = string.Format(stSql, 
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value, 
            Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value), 
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), 
            Convert.ToInt32( dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value),
            Convert.ToInt32( dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value));
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stSql, oleConn);
    cmd.Connection = oleConn;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```